# Sort List or foreach which would be faster

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a dictionary of items with the ID as a key.  Those items also have a timespan value.  One function needs to do something with the items where timespan > searchTime.

Would sorting the list fist be faster or would the sorting take as long as the foreach function.  I wish there was a sorted dictionary that allowed you to sort on a different key.

Which would be faster?

```
List<StatePath> timeSorted = new List<StatePath>();
timeSorted = itemDict.ToList();
timeSorted.Sort((ts1, ts2) => TimeSpan.Compare(ts1.time, ts2.time));
int i = timeSorted.Count -1;
while((i > 0) && timeSorted[i].time >= searchTime)
{
  //do something
}
```

or

```
foreach(var curItem in itemDict.Values)
{
  if(curItem.time >= searchTime)
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pOIXdO both seem the same.

Comment: John, I think you are right they are the same.  Post this ans an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing two options, there's almost always context that can change the outcome. If you're not **measuring** both, you should be. And this presumes it even matters; odds are, the difference here is **not** driving the performance for you app.

That said, I'd probably do it like this:

```
foreach(var curItem in itemDict.Values.Where(i => i.time >= searchTime))
{
    //do something
}
```

Specifically, I wonder what you think happens when you call `timeSorted.Sort()`. This method clearly must run it's own `foreach` loop or similar in order to complete the operation.

Comment: I was not sure if the sort had faster methods than the for each.  Thanks for the code, I didn't even think about combining the linq in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the foreach loop should be faster.  The best possible speed for sort is O(n log n), while your for loop is O(n).

In practice, of course, you should test and see which one is faster.